# Grails 2.3.8 where is the owned object's back reference to its owner persisted?

Tags: grails

I noticed that on an owned object participating in a bidirectional `belongsTo` type relationship I can see the owned object's back reference to it's owner using something like

```
println ownedInstance.properties
```

but i can't see it in the dbconsole as a column in the table (default in memory h2). So where are these properties stored in the db then? I don't even see a corresponding join table.

Comment: Which columns do you see now in `OwnedInstance` table?

Comment: @dmahapatro When the relationship was unidirectional, `ownedInstance` had `ID,VERSION,and programmer declared properties`. Once I made the relationship bidirectional, I expected the `ownedInstance` to also have a back reference column for back reference to `owner` but I did not see it. However, if in grails debug console plugin I do `println ownedInstance.properties` I do see it(the back reference), that confused me why I see it in one place and not the other. So, I thought might be in a join table but none existed-now this part made sens becaus wy wud there be a join table for a bi-dir rel?.